# Rails simple_calendar sum field by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the simple_calendar gem in my Rails app to display a calendar that automatically filters Activities by each day in the month view:

**profile.html.erb**

```
<%= month_calendar events: @activities do |date, activities| %>
  <%= date.strftime("%e") %>
  <div class="totalminutes-container">
    <span class="totalminutes">X</span> mins # this needs to be the sum of activity.minutes_out for the date
  </div>

  <% activities.each do |activity| %>
    <p>
      <%= activity.minutes_out %>
    </p>
    <div class="activity <%= activity.name.delete(' ') %>">
        <%= activity.name %>
        <div class="timeout">
            <%= activity.created_at.strftime("%l:%M%P") %> - <%= activity.updated_at.strftime("%l:%M%P") %>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**What I would like to do is for each day, display a sum of activity.minutes_out for each day and display it on the calendar**

Answer (score 0):

I think two strategies...

1) create a class method that return the `total_minutes` for a date and call there `Activities.total_minutes(date)`.

or

2) com o seguinte código:

```
activities.map{|a| a.minutes_out if a.date == date }.compact!.inject(0){  |sum, i| sum + i }
```

I didn't test so maybe it needs some changes to workout.

Comment: undefined method `date' for #<Activity:0x007fad745d6028>

Comment: Oh, sorry... you should change a.date for the method in the activity object that eu check the date!

Comment: I don't know this gem but `activities` contain the activities for a range of date ou for one date? Because, if it is for one date you can simplify: `activities.map(&:minutes_out).compact!.inject(0){  |sum, i| sum + i }`

Comment: The simplified version is adding up the minutes correctly, but it is not taking to account the date. Right now every day in the month is showing 5 minutes out (which is the total sum of minutes_out)

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do: `<%= @activities.where(created_at: date.midnight..date.end_of_day).map(&:minutes_out).compact!.inject(0){ |sum, i| sum + i } %>` but I'm getting this error: `undefined method `inject' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Looking the doc, "Then in your view, you can pass in the events option to render. The meetings will automatically be filtered out by day for you.". So, activities (not @activities) is already filtered by the day... try to call the simplified version inside the block because it is already taking to account the date...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134288/discussion-between-thiago-ururay-and-beaconhill).